# Android: AIDL service doesn't generate completely after gradle upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, aidl

I'm developing an app fora SUNMI device, which has an integrated thermal printer, I have its aidl services, everything was implemented and working fine, the project was working under gradle 3.4.
when I upgraded to gradle 3.5.3 the project couldn't build and it throw this error `error: reached end of file while parsing` when I go to check the generated file i find it incomplete:

The generated file (the file is too long, so I copied only the begining and the end of it):

```
/*
 * This file is auto-generated.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 */
package woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5;
public interface IWoyouService extends android.os.IInterface
{
/** Local-side IPC implementation stub class. */
public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements       woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService
{
private static final java.lang.String DESCRIPTOR = "woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService";
/** Construct the stub at attach it to the interface. */
public Stub()
{
this.attachInterface(this, DESCRIPTOR);
}
/**
 * Cast an IBinder object into an woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService interface,
 * generating a proxy if needed.
 */
public static woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService asInterface(android.os.IBinder obj)
{
if ((obj==null)) {
return null;
}
.
.
.
return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
}
}
}
private static class Proxy implements woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.IWoyouService
{
private android.os.IBinder mRemote;
Proxy(android.os.IBinder remote)
{
mRemote = remote;
}
@Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return mRemote;
}
public java.lang.String getInterfaceDescriptor()
{
return DESCRIPTOR;
```

this is the AIDL file:

```
package woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5;

import woyou.aidlservice.jiuiv5.ICallback;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import com.sunmi.trans.TransBean;

interface IWoyouService
{

void updateFirmware();


int getFirmwareStatus();


String getServiceVersion();


void printerInit(in ICallback callback);


void printerSelfChecking(in ICallback callback);

String getPrinterSerialNo();


String getPrinterVersion();

String getPrinterModal();


void getPrintedLength(in ICallback callback);


void lineWrap(int n, in ICallback callback);


void sendRAWData(in byte[] data, in ICallback callback);


void setAlignment(int alignment, in ICallback callback);


void setFontName(String typeface, in ICallback callback);


void setFontSize(float fontsize, in ICallback callback);

void printText(String text, in ICallback callback);


void printTextWithFont(String text, String typeface, float fontsize, in ICallback callback);


void printColumnsText(in String[] colsTextArr, in int[] colsWidthArr, in int[] colsAlign, in ICallback callback);


void printBitmap(in Bitmap bitmap, in ICallback callback);

void printBarCode(String data, int symbology, int height, int width, int textposition,  in ICallback callback);

void printQRCode(String data, int modulesize, int errorlevel, in ICallback callback);


void printOriginalText(String text, in ICallback callback);


void commitPrint(in TransBean[] transbean, in ICallback callback);


void commitPrinterBuffer();


void enterPrinterBuffer(in boolean clean);



void exitPrinterBuffer(in boolean commit);


void printColumnsString(in String[] colsTextArr, in int[] colsWidthArr, in int[] colsAlign, in ICallback callback);


void printBitmapCustom(in Bitmap bitmap, in int type, in ICallback callback);
}
```

since i need that gradle upgrade because it is required for some firebase stuff, i need to figure this out, I already invalidated the cashes and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue ...just passed it by getting the previously generated .java files , and then deleting the aidl files and its generated files

Answer (score 0):

Adding/modifying in `gradle.properties` solved it for me:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```